# How to use PrimaryScrollController in multiple views at the same time

Tags: dart, flutter

I am using the `PrimaryScrollController` to in a custom stateful widget which is basically a `ListView` with code to load items from the server as the user scrolls.  I need the `PrimaryScrollController` so that tapping the top of the app bar on iOS scrolls back to the top.

I am using this same widget in multiple pages, which are controlled by a `BottomNavigationBar`. I am also trying to persist state, so that when the user scrolls, then changes to another tab in the bottom nav bar, and then returns to the first tab, the scroll position and all the items loaded from the server will still be there.

To persist the state of the pages I'm using an `IndexedStack`. However, since both pages are using the `PrimaryScrollController` at the same time I'm getting a long chain of the same error message in the console: `flutter: Another exception was thrown: ScrollController attached to multiple scroll views.`
I'm understanding that this is telling me that I shouldn't use the same `ScrollController` in multiple views. The simple solution would be to just create a new instance for each view. However, I must use the same `ScrollController` because I need the `PrimaryScrollController` for the tap the app bar on iOS to work.

<s>If I just ignore the errors, the actual code works the way I want it to, each page retains its own state.</s>
Actually, it doesn't work the way I want it to. The listeners don't work when they are on sperate pages.

I created a sample app to show the problem:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

List<Widget> _pages = [
  BodyWidget(key: PageStorageKey(1)),
  BodyWidget(key: PageStorageKey(2)),
];

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _currentPage = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: IndexedStack(
        index: _currentPage,
        children: _pages,
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
          currentIndex: _currentPage,
          onTap: (int index) {
            setState(() {
              _currentPage = index;
            });
          },
          items: [
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.star_border), title: Text('page 1')),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.crop_square), title: Text('page 2'))
          ]),
    );
  }
}

class BodyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  BodyWidget({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _BodyWidgetState createState() => _BodyWidgetState();
}

class _BodyWidgetState extends State<BodyWidget> {
  ScrollController _scrollController;
  List<int> numbers = [];

  void dataGenerator() {
    // simulate loading items from server
    var rng = new Random();
    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
      if (this.mounted) {
        setState(() {
          numbers.add(rng.nextInt(100));
        });
      }
    }
    print('loaded more items');
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    // This delay is required to get the build context
    Future.delayed(
      Duration.zero,
      () {
        _scrollController = PrimaryScrollController.of(context);
        _scrollController.addListener(() {
          if (_scrollController.position.pixels >=
              (_scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent - 50)) {
            dataGenerator();
          }
        });
        dataGenerator();
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: numbers.length,
      controller: _scrollController,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return Container(
          child: Card(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                SizedBox(
                  height: 15,
                ),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text('Random number: ' + numbers[index].toString()),
                    Text('Index: ' + index.toString())
                  ],
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 15,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

This is the error that is thrown:

```
flutter: ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY FOUNDATION LIBRARY ╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
flutter: The following assertion was thrown while dispatching notifications for ScrollController:
flutter: ScrollController attached to multiple scroll views.
flutter: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/scroll_controller.dart': Failed assertion: line 111 pos 12:
flutter: '_positions.length == 1'
flutter:
flutter: Either the assertion indicates an error in the framework itself, or we should provide substantially
flutter: more information in this error message to help you determine and fix the underlying cause.
flutter: In either case, please report this assertion by filing a bug on GitHub:
flutter:   https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new?template=BUG.md
flutter:
flutter: When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
flutter: #2      ScrollController.position 
package:flutter/…/widgets/scroll_controller.dart:111
flutter: #3      _BodyWidgetState.initState.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>
package:primaryscrollcontroller_test/main.dart:97
flutter: #4      ChangeNotifier.notifyListeners 
package:flutter/…/foundation/change_notifier.dart:206
flutter: #5      ChangeNotifier.notifyListeners 
package:flutter/…/foundation/change_notifier.dart:206
flutter: #6      ScrollPosition.notifyListeners 
package:flutter/…/widgets/scroll_position.dart:696
flutter: #7      ScrollPosition.setPixels 
package:flutter/…/widgets/scroll_position.dart:218
flutter: #8      ScrollPositionWithSingleContext.setPixels 
package:flutter/…/widgets/scroll_position_with_single_context.dart:84
flutter: #9      ScrollPositionWithSingleContext.applyUserOffset 
package:flutter/…/widgets/scroll_position_with_single_context.dart:127
flutter: #10     ScrollDragController.update 
package:flutter/…/widgets/scroll_activity.dart:372
flutter: #11     ScrollableState._handleDragUpdate 
package:flutter/…/widgets/scrollable.dart:496
flutter: #12     DragGestureRecognizer.handleEvent.<anonymous closure> 
flutter: #13     GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback 
package:flutter/…/gestures/recognizer.dart:166
flutter: #14     DragGestureRecognizer.handleEvent 
package:flutter/…/gestures/monodrag.dart:182
flutter: #15     PointerRouter._dispatch 
package:flutter/…/gestures/pointer_router.dart:73
flutter: #16     PointerRouter.route 
package:flutter/…/gestures/pointer_router.dart:101
flutter: #17     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding.handleEvent 
package:flutter/…/gestures/binding.dart:221
flutter: #18     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding.dispatchEvent 
package:flutter/…/gestures/binding.dart:199
flutter: #19     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding._handlePointerEvent 
package:flutter/…/gestures/binding.dart:156
flutter: #20     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue 
package:flutter/…/gestures/binding.dart:102
flutter: #21     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket 
package:flutter/…/gestures/binding.dart:86
flutter: #25     _invoke1  (dart:ui/hooks.dart:233:10)
flutter: #26     _dispatchPointerDataPacket  (dart:ui/hooks.dart:154:5)
flutter: (elided 5 frames from class _AssertionError and package dart:async)
flutter:
flutter: The ScrollController sending notification was:
flutter:   ScrollController#be798(2 clients)
flutter: ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
flutter: Another exception was thrown: ScrollController attached to multiple scroll views.
flutter: Another exception was thrown: ScrollController attached to multiple scroll views.
flutter: Another exception was thrown: ScrollController attached to multiple scroll views.
flutter: Another exception was thrown: ScrollController attached to multiple scroll views.
```

The line `flutter: Another exception was thrown: ScrollController attached to multiple scroll views.` just keeps repeating many more times

How do I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Old, and there are lots of answers out there. I had similar issue, a few months ago:

The problem as the issue states, you have multiple positions (several scrollable views).

Declare as usual:

```
ScrollController scrollController;
```

//Note, Position, contains the información regarding the scroll offset, physics etc, this "[positions](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ScrollController/positions.html)" is an iterable., you might guess, here its where **all** scrolls "position" are stored (one for each scrollable view attached for this @scrollController" .

```
final scrollPositions = scrollController.positions;
```

//given the positions length I grabbed the latest one, which in my use case was always the last one (going back and forward doing new lists), you can adapt it to grab the position information depending on your needs.

```
final scrollPositionImInterested = scrollPositions
        .elementAt(scrollController.positions.length - 1);
```

hope this helps someone in the same needs